# My shadow root has a margin, how do I get rid of that margin?

Tags: javascript, html, css

All my pages have a margin:8 from the shadow root on the body, no matter how I create them (atom, notepad). I didn't create a shadow root, it seems to be just there. How to get rid of that margin, or set it to 0? Maybe something in javascript?

Comment: what is shadow root ? provide some link or code it won't help like that !

Comment: `body { margin: 0; }` in CSS. 8px is the default for most browsers (even if you don't specify it). You have to reset this value to 0 or use something like normalize.css.

Comment: Margin is defaulted to 8 px on the body, in your css ad `body{margin: 0px}`

Comment: Didn't know it had that default. Thank you!